# Check whether a repository would be pushed in a shell script

Tags: bash, git

I need to check whether a `git push` command would actually push something in a bash script. I cannot work with exit codes because it is zero for both a successful push and the "no push necessary"-case.

This is my current workaround, but it's probably not very elegant.

```
# some code that does things with a repo

# check whether push is necessary
push_output=$(git push origin "$BRANCH" --dry-run 2>&1)
if [[ "$push_output" == "Everything up-to-date" ]]; then
    echo "no push necessary."
    # do something
else
    # do something else
fi

# more code here
```

Comment: `git log --oneline @{u}.. | grep .` is what I have been using, probably from the duplicate I just found.

Comment: @tripleee I'm not sure that duplicate applies 100%. The answers seem to be tailored for inspection of the output by a human.

Comment: Many of them yes, but others not.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you. I went with checking whether `diff_output=$(git diff "origin/$BRANCH..HEAD")` is empty.